# xdebug doesn't return variables

Tags: php, windows, windows-7, xdebug

I'm trying to work with xdebug on my remote machine. The connection seems ok since the execution stops if i set a breakpoint and i see the context of the call ($_GLOBALS). But i can't look into the variables.

Enabled the remote_log on the server and see the following:

> <- context_get -i 330 -c 1
>   -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_get" transaction_id="330" context="1"><property name="$_COOKIE" fullname="$_COOKIE" address="57264352" type="array" children="1" numchildren="1" page="0" pagesize="30">**... huge repesponse with all globals ...**</property></response>
>
> <- property_get -i 331 -n $b
>   -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="property_get" transaction_id="331" status="break" reason="ok">**<error code="300"><message><![CDATA[can not get property]]></message></error>**</response>

I get the "can not get property" error every time i want to access the value of a variable.

Server runs

- Apache 2.2.7 vc9,
- php 5.3.16 and
- xdebug 2.2.5 on a
- windows 7 32 bit machine.

I'm trying to debug from a client machine using netbeans 8.0.

Anyone an idea how i can solve that?
Would be really nice to be able to debug.

thanks for any help!

- Johannes

**Update**

I could resolve that issue by unchecking the netbeans debug-option "stop at first line". The debugger stopped - but not at my breakpoint :P

Comment: Have you checked "Watches and Ballon Evaluation" in Debugging tab of PHP options in Netbeans?

Comment: Nope - but it doesn't work either "Watches and Balloon Evaluation" is ticked or not.

Comment: Updating to the actual PHP 5.3.28 didn't help either. 

Anyone an idea why xdebug doesn't return variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve that issue by unchecking the netbeans debug-option "stop at first line". The debugger stopped - but not at my breakpoint :P